# Getting error while placing pagination on search in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-2

I am getting an error while placing pagination on search in Codeigniter. I tried the following code. on moving to next page it showing an error page.

```
$search = $this->input->get('query');
    $data['snippets'] =  $this->Constant_model->search($search);
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "search?query=".$search;
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->Constant_model->search_query_result_count($search);
    $config["per_page"] = 12;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['search_results'] = $this->Constant_model->search_query($config["per_page"], $page,$search);
```

A model function used in the pagination code. Here limit the database to show the results.

```
public function search_query($limit, $start, $query)
{
    // $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('snippets');
    $this->db->like('snippets_name', $query);

    $query = $this->db->get();


    $result = $query->result();

    $this->db->save_queries = false;

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: What error and where? Help us, help you.

Comment: I am not getting results on page #2. its blank...

Comment: @adamoffat yes I am limiting the results and its showing 12 results on the first page as declared in the code

Comment: Check this out: https://www.guru99.com/codeigniter-pagination.html

Comment: @adamoffat I don't think this link is related to me... as its simple pagination

Comment: I don't think you have provided us enough context of the situation to provide useful help. As @Script47 stated.

Comment: I want to apply pagination on the basis of search queries...

Comment: What more information do you need? please tell i will update...

Comment: We need to look at the model and the error that you are receiving when trying to navigate to the second page. Also, a clear cut question will help others to understand what exactly the problem is you are having.

Comment: I am not getting any error. on moving to next page getting a blank page...

Comment: updated, please check